# Cloudera manager parcel installations dips down to a smaller percentage from a higher percentage

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Say for example while downloading the parcel it downloads it till 10 % and suddenly dips down to a lower percentage repeatedly.
Any idea on what should be checked or regarding issue.
The cloudera version is 5.4.5 , and parcel download is being carried out from the admin console.

Comment: Which parcel are you trying to download ?. Sometimes, because of checksum mismatch, the download will fail and it will retry. Check your firewall and network connectivity. If your firewall is blocking the download, it will show similar result.

Comment: Two parcels (1) CDH 5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.po.7 and (2) KAFKA 0.8.2.0-1.kafka 1.3.1.po.9

Comment: I 've turned firewall off , checked connectivity and all seems to done correctly.Still its retrying.Have been doing it since two days bot no significant progress ;(

Comment: Try downloading this parcel manually and deploy it in a local web server and then add the url in  the cloudera manager

Comment: Hey Amal , thanks for advice , i found the supported OS document for cdh5 and din't  found any support for Ubuntu trusty while i m using trusty so i guess that should be issue